# Why does Unity screen blank out over XDMCP?

Tags: xdmcp

My XDMCP sessions display fine until I login. I've checked all logs and settings for this and can't find anything wrong, this works fine on other systems so I'm wondering if this has anything to do with the underlying hardware or an application that loads when logging in.

System details:
- Ubuntu 12.04 (Desktop, installed via Alternate CD for RAID)
- 8GB of RAM
- Core2Quad CPU @ 2.40GHz
- Gigabit Network (Ethernet)

Other notes:
- Running with the onscreen keyboard enabled
- Works fine when logging in locally

Pre-login:
[image]
Once logged in: 
[image]

Comment: Try logging in to Ubuntu 2D instead of "Ubuntu"...

Comment: @izx Thank you, this resolved the issue. I can't believe I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved by using Ubuntu 2D. Ubuntu 3D is selected by default on login. When logging in, click the Ubuntu icon next to your name and select "Ubuntu 2D".